# How to use testng to test serivce with session read and write?

Tags: spring, session, testng

My service needs to get object from session like this:

```
  @Service("UsageService")
  @Scope(value="session")  
  public class UsageServiceImpl implements UsageService
  {
    @Override
    public void doAnalysis()
    {
       // get data from session
       ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
       HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
             ......
    }
  }
```

Test code like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "test-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class UsageServiceImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
        @Autowired
        private UsageService service;

        @Test
        public void testAnalysis()
        {
       service.doAnalysis(null);
        }
}
```

And I have followed http://tarunsapra.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/junit-spring-session-and-request-scope-beans/'s suggestion add this to test-context.xml

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="session">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

When I run text I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside   of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

As error messages says:I am refering request attributes outside of an actual web request due to I launch service by testng not a http request,how can I make service with session read-write testable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mockito in your unit test to mock the RequestAttributes object to return what you want, and then call RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(RequestAttributes) with your mock/stub before you start your test.

Comment: I think it not can't get value but can't do it like this